# Angularjs Component and $watch with Binding In ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, es6-promise, angularjs-components

Hi am working on AngularJS Component, need help how to use $watch inside Constructor() as below I attached my code structure.

```
 import template from './Mypage.component.html';
 export const MyComponent = {
 template,
 bindings: {
   myData: '<'
 },
 controller: class MyController {
   constructor($scope) {
   $scope.$watch(() => this.myData, newVal => {
    this._myFunction();
  });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `$scope` dependency inside `$inject` array and use it in constructor should work. But please find below suggestion.

```
controller: class MyController {
  $inject = ['$scope'];
  constructor($scope) {
    $scope.$watch(() => this.myData, newVal => {
      this._myFunction();
    });
  }
}
```

---

We all know `$watch` does fires on each digest cycle to update `data bidnings` on page and it is bad for performance reason. Rather you could use `$onChanges` lifecycle hook of angularjs component so which will only get fire when bindings value gets changed

```
controller: class MyController {
  constructor($scope) {}
  $onChanges(newVal) {
     this._myFunction();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$onChanges()` method instead of `$scope.$watch()`

```
class MyController {
  constructor() {
    // Your constructor...
  }

  $onChanges(changedObj){
    // Expect myData changes
    console.log(changedObj)
  }
}
```

More info [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html#onchanges)